# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "company_company" does not exist when running makemigrations

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I have a Django app but when I try to run makemigrations get an error:

```
  File "C:\Users\EDUARDO\Desktop\ProyectoSoft\smarthbatch\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "company_company" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "company_company"
                                          ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\EDUARDO\Desktop\ProyectoSoft\smarthbatch\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\_init_.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\EDUARDO\Desktop\ProyectoSoft\smarthbatch\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\_init_.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\EDUARDO\Desktop\ProyectoSoft\smarthbatch\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\EDUARDO\Desktop\ProyectoSoft\smarthbatch\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 368, in execute
    self.check()
  File "C:\Users\EDUARDO\Desktop\ProyectoSoft\smarthbatch\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 396, in check
    databases=databases,
  File "C:\Users\EDUARDO\Desktop\ProyectoSoft\smarthbatch\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 70, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\EDUARDO\Desktop\ProyectoSoft\smarthbatch\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\EDUARDO\Desktop\ProyectoSoft\smarthbatch\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\EDUARDO\Desktop\ProyectoSoft\smarthbatch\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 408, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\EDUARDO\Desktop\ProyectoSoft\smarthbatch\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in _get_
    res = instance._dict_[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\EDUARDO\Desktop\ProyectoSoft\smarthbatch\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 589, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\EDUARDO\Desktop\ProyectoSoft\smarthbatch\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in _get_
    res = instance._dict_[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\EDUARDO\Desktop\ProyectoSoft\smarthbatch\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 582, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\EDUARDO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\_init_.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\EDUARDO\Desktop\ProyectoSoft\smarthbatch\bpmdoc\config\urls.py", line 32, in <module>
    path ( "company/", include('core.company.urls'))
  File "C:\Users\EDUARDO\Desktop\ProyectoSoft\smarthbatch\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\EDUARDO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\_init_.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\EDUARDO\Desktop\ProyectoSoft\smarthbatch\bpmdoc\core\company\urls.py", line 6, in <module>
    from core.company.views import CompanyCreateView, CompanyUpdateView, CompanyListView
  File "C:\Users\EDUARDO\Desktop\ProyectoSoft\smarthbatch\bpmdoc\core\company\views.py", line 18, in <module>
    class CompanyCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, ValidatePermissionRequiredMixin, CreateView):
  File "C:\Users\EDUARDO\Desktop\ProyectoSoft\smarthbatch\bpmdoc\core\company\views.py", line 26, in CompanyCreateView
    algo = Company.objects.filter () .count()
  File "C:\Users\EDUARDO\Desktop\ProyectoSoft\smarthbatch\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 411, in count
    return self.query.get_count(using=self.db)
  File "C:\Users\EDUARDO\Desktop\ProyectoSoft\smarthbatch\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 515, in get_count
    number = obj.get_aggregation(using, ['_count'])['_count']
  File "C:\Users\EDUARDO\Desktop\ProyectoSoft\smarthbatch\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 500, in get_aggregation
    result = compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE)
  File "C:\Users\EDUARDO\Desktop\ProyectoSoft\smarthbatch\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1156, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\EDUARDO\Desktop\ProyectoSoft\smarthbatch\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\EDUARDO\Desktop\ProyectoSoft\smarthbatch\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\EDUARDO\Desktop\ProyectoSoft\smarthbatch\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\EDUARDO\Desktop\ProyectoSoft\smarthbatch\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\EDUARDO\Desktop\ProyectoSoft\smarthbatch\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in _exit_
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\EDUARDO\Desktop\ProyectoSoft\smarthbatch\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "company_company" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "company_company"
```

This is the conflicting view:

```
    class CompanyCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, ValidatePermissionRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Company
    form_class = CompanyForms
    template_name = 'company/create.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('company:company_list')
    permission_required = 'erp.add_company'

    try :
        Company.objects.get(id=1)        
        def get(self, request, **kwargs):
            return redirect('company:company_list')
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        pass

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super ().dispatch (request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = {}
        try:
            action = request.POST['action']
            if action == 'add':
                form = self.get_form()
                if form.is_valid():
                    data = form.save()
                    messages.success(request, f'Compañia creada satisfactoriamente!')
                else:
                    messages.error (request, form.errors)
            else:
                data['error'] = 'No ha ingresado datos en los campos'
        except Exception as e:
            data['error'] = str(e)
        return JsonResponse(data)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['tittle'] = 'Configurar Compañia'
        context['entity'] = 'Configurar Compañia'
        context['action'] = 'add'
        context['list_url'] = reverse_lazy ('company:company_list')
        return context
```

this is url.py from company app

```
from django.urls import path
# url media files
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from core.company.views import CompanyCreateView, CompanyUpdateView, CompanyListView

app_name = 'company'

urlpatterns = [
    path ('add/', CompanyCreateView.as_view (), name='company_create'),
    path ('update/<int:pk>/', CompanyUpdateView.as_view (), name='company_update'),
    path('list/', CompanyListView.as_view(), name='company_list'),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                      document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Basically I need to check if there is any row in company table redirect to company list view else redirect to company create view

Any idea how to solve it?

I don't know why this doesn't let me run migrations properly

Thanks so much for any help

Comment: The issue is in `CompanyCreateView`, can you add it to the question

Comment: Thanks for your comment, just added the requested view

Comment: What is that defining a `get` method in a `try/except` all about? It's what's causing the error, what's it's purpose?

Comment: Cuz in this part:

`try :
        Company.objects.get(id=1)        
        def get(self, request, **kwargs):
            return redirect('company:company_list')
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        pass`

When i do: Company.objects.get(id=1) if there is any objet in db i need it to override get method to redirect to listview

but is there is not any object in DB it raises a ObjectDoesNotExist exception so it that case the get method must not been overriden

Comment: I'm not sure what you are showing there. Just define the `get` method without any "complications", it only returns a redirect?

Comment: I just need to redirect or define the get method ONLY if there are data in company table, if not data in company table don't need to define the get method or make a redirection

Comment: I don't know if there is another way to validate company table in data base is not empty and make a redirection if so

Comment: I don't see the harm in redirecting to `company_list` even when there is no data. Even so, companies may be added __after__ the `CompanyCreateView` class has been created, do you intend to add the `get` method then? If you must only redirect when there are `Company` entries then perhaps performing the check inside the view may work better

Comment: that's the view, how do i validate or check if  there are company entries?

Comment: `Company.objects.exists()` is the quickest/most performant way of checking that

Comment: the create view must be loaded only if there are no entries in `Company` if there are already an entry in `Company` then it must load the list view

Comment: @IainShelvington i change it to:  if Company.objects.exists() :
        def get(self, request, **kwargs) :
            return redirect('company:company_list')

Comment: but when trying to run the makemigrations I get: File "C:/Users/EDUARDO/Desktop/ProyectoSoft/smarthbatch/bpmdoc\core\company\views.py", line 26, in CompanyCreateView
    if Company.objects.exists() :

Comment: django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "company_company" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "company_company" LIMIT 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! On my view just changed this:

```
    try :
            Company.objects.get(id=1)        
            def get(self, request, **kwargs):
                return redirect('company:company_list')
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            pass
    
   def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
     return super ().dispatch (request, *args, **kwargs)
```

to this:

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
  if Company.objects.exists():       
    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        return redirect('company:company_list')
  return super (CompanyCreateView, self).dispatch (request, *args, **kwargs)
```

This kind of validations should be done inside the dispatch method, so that way you don't get the ProgrammingError exception when migrating to a fully empty database

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by this line:

```
Company.objects.get(id=1)
```

You are trying to get an object from the table but that table does not exist.